# open project visual studio 2010 unhandled exception win32 in devenv.exe [2940]

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

When I try to open an existing project in Visual Studio 2010, I've a choice between 'debug' and 'close program'. When I click on 'debug', I've the following message :

Unhandled exception win32 in devenv.exe [2940]

Do you have a solution ?

Thank you

Comment: Does the exception occur when you open VS 2010, or when you open a .net project in 2010?

Comment: Does the exception occur no matter which project you open, or is it occurring for a specific project?

Answer (score 0):

From http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3edad88b-a35b-48b6-9c19-a20233d7f874/an-unhandled-microsoft-net-framework-exception-occurred-in-devenvexe-3472?forum=netfx64bit:

> If the exception occurs when you opening VS2010, you need to post in
>   [Visual Studio Editor forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vseditor).
>
> If the exception occurs when you opening anyone of .NET projects from
>   VS2010, it may be caused by .NET Framework. You can follow the tool:
>   [.NET Framework Setup Verification Tool User's Guide](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2008/10/13/8999004.aspx) to check whether
>   .NET Framework is correctly installed. If not, please try to
>   re-install .NET Framework.

So, it sounds like a reasonable first step is to verify you .Net install. If that fails, reinstall. I didn't see any quick matches for this error on Google, which leads me to believe that there's the possibility that it's a corrupted install.